# Change a html (text) to php (Users name)

Tags: php, jquery, html

On my index page what I'm trying to achieve is after login a dropdown button on the top right of my page to change from "Account" to "Welcome [User]" and the buttons inside to change from "Login" to "View Account" & "Log out"
I have the PHP code that says "Welcome [User]" but I'm not too sure on how to switch them out.

```
<?php 
    session_start(); 
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>    
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">

<head>
    <title>Bootstrap Case</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="../../dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <link href="../../assets/css/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <title>Carousel Template for Bootstrap</title>

    <!-- Just for debugging purposes. Don't actually copy these 2 lines! -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="../../assets/js/ie8-responsive-file-warning.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <script src="../../assets/js/ie-emulation-modes-warning.js"></script>

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="carousel.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<!-- NAVBAR ================================================== -->

<body style="height:1500px">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Jobsite</a>
            </div>
        <div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav" style="display: inline-block;">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Who are we?</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Make a resume</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Search for jobs</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>

            <li class="dropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"><b>
                <!-- logged in user information -->
                <?php  if (isset($_SESSION['username'] )): ?>
                    <p>Welcome <strong><?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?></strong></p>
                    <p>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <a href="index.php?logout='1'" style="color: red;">logout</a> </p>
                            <li><a href="http://localhost/registration/login.php">Login</a></li>
                            ...
                <?php endif ?>
                ...
            ...
        </div>
    </b>

//-----------------
//  Etc...
//-------------------
```

I've seen(and attempted with no luck) `str_replace()`. I'm not sure how the best way to do this is.

Server.php

```
<?php 
session_start();

// variable declaration
$username = "";
$email    = "";
$errors = array(); 
$_SESSION['success'] = "";

// connect to database
$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'registration');

// REGISTER USER
if (isset($_POST['reg_user'])) {
    // receive all input values from the form
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['username']);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['email']);
    $password_1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password_1']);
    $password_2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password_2']);

    // form validation: ensure that the form is correctly filled
    if (empty($username)) { array_push($errors, "Username is required"); }
    if (empty($email)) { array_push($errors, "Email is required"); }
    if (empty($password_1)) { array_push($errors, "Password is required"); }

    if ($password_1 != $password_2) {
        array_push($errors, "The two passwords do not match");
    }

    // register user if there are no errors in the form
    if (count($errors) == 0) {
        $password = md5($password_1);//encrypt the password before saving in the database
        $query = "INSERT INTO users (username, email, password) 
                  VALUES('$username', '$email', '$password')";
        mysqli_query($db, $query);

        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        $_SESSION['success'] = "You are now logged in";
        header('location: index.php');
    }

}

// ... 

// LOGIN USER
if (isset($_POST['login_user'])) {
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['username']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password']);

    if (empty($username)) {
        array_push($errors, "Username is required");
    }
    if (empty($password)) {
        array_push($errors, "Password is required");
    }

    if (count($errors) == 0) {
        $password = md5($password);
        $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";
        $results = mysqli_query($db, $query);

        if (mysqli_num_rows($results) == 1) {
            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
            $_SESSION['success'] = "You are now logged in";
            header('location: index.php');
        }else {
            array_push($errors, "Wrong username/password combination");
        }
    }
}
```

?>

Comment: what error you faced ?

Comment: the str_replace didn't really have an error it was more the fact that i could only figure out how to replace text with text not with another php code (i believe due to the brackets its placed in?)              because <?php  if (isset($_SESSION['username'] )): ?>   has to somehow fit in-    <?php
echo str_replace("world","Peter","Hello world!");  ?>  (or something like that)

Comment: Can you add your php code. Especially the part where you set the session?

Comment: I added the server.php one (but there is also- user.php, errors.php, login.php, and registration.php.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the whole dropdown content using php, so it shows what you want on each case. Something like this (adapt the content of each option to your case)...

```
<li class="dropdown">
  <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"><b>

  <?php if (isset($_SESSION['username'] )) { ?>
    <p>Welcome <strong><?=$_SESSION['username']?></strong></p>
    <p><a href="index.php?viewaccount=<?=$_SESSION['username']?>" style="color: red;">logout</a></p>
    <p><a href="index.php?logout='1'" style="color: red;">logout</a></p>
  <?php } else { ?>
    <p><a href="http://localhost/registration/login.php">Login</a></p>
  <?php } ?>
```

You'll have to tweak it a little bit to use the html element distribution you prefer, but I hope you understand the idea. Just create all the dropdown content for each case.

I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Ok got it thanks to A. Iglesias's code-

```
     <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Who are we?</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Make a resume</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Search for jobs</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>

  <?php if (isset($_SESSION['username'] )) { ?>
 <li class="dropdown">
  <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"><b>
 <p>Welcome <strong><?=$_SESSION['username']?></strong></p>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu">
   <a href="index.php?logout='1'" style="color: red;">logout</a> </p>
 </b>
  </a>
  </div>
  <?php } else { ?>
  <li class="dropdown">
  <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"><b>
  <p>Account</p>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <p><a href="http://localhost/registration/login.php">Login</a></p>
  <?php } ?>

</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</nav>
```

so now If a user is logged in it will show "Welcome [User]" in a drop-down bar (which includes the log out and soon to be account page) and when no one is logged in it shows "Account" which has a drop down to a log in page. Thanks Guys!